# Ubuntu 20.04 SFTP Server Users can't Login sporadically. Fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sftp

I have a problem with an Ubuntu 20 SFTP Server.

My SFTP is working fine. After a view days all SFTP Users can't login.
in my auth.log i see this "error":

> Jul  7 11:23:01 lu20ftp systemd-logind[796]: New session 980054 of user xy.
>
> Jul  7 11:23:01 lu20ftp sshd[3697432]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/var/sftp/"
>
> Jul  7 11:23:01 lu20ftp sshd[3697170]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user xy

my sshd_config looks like this:

```
   Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
   Match Group sftp
     ChrootDirectory %h
     ForceCommand internal-sftp
     AllowTcpForwarding no
```

My Folders look like this:

> drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jun 15 14:27 xy
>
> drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 23 09:21 xyz
>
> drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 23 09:24 xyz1
>
> drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 20 09:50 xyz2

Inside the folder:

> drwxr-xr-x  2 xy sftp  4096 Jul  7 14:20 test
>
> drwxr-xr-x+ 2 xy sftp 20480 Jul  7 14:20 test2

my user (`/etc/passwd`) looks like this:

> xy:x:1002:1001::/var/sftp/xy:/usr/sbin/nologin

when I run the state:

`chmod 755 -R /var/sftp/` then it's working for view days again.

What's wrong here? I don't find a solution for this problem.

Happy to get help